# Precision improvement - recursive sequence plot for Newton method

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, recursion, fpu

The Newton method for solving x+x^2=0 works only four steps, as the iterates are not computed accurately.

The fpu library allows much increased precision, but I don't know how to use.

Could somebody tell me how to create a vector/array in order to keep the iterates for later plotting in tikz?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary {fpu}
\begin{document}

    \pgfmathfloatsetextprecision{3} %maximum precision
    \xdef\Nit{9}  % no of iterations
    \def\x{0.5}  % x current, initialized, determining xnew
    %\pgfmathfloattoextentedprecision{\x}  %not allowed
    %\pgfmathsetmacro\x{\pgfmathresult}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\Nit} {

          % \pgfmathfloatadd, \pgfmathfloatdiv here instead, for each operation??
          \pgfmathsetmacro\xn{\x - (\x + \x^2)/(1 + 2*\x)}  % new x
          \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\x}
          \pgfmathfloattomacro{\pgfmathresult}{\F}{\M}{\E} 
          Flags: \F; Mantissa \M; Exponent \E \\
          \xdef\x{\xn}  %update x
    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. Does it has to be an embedded code? I.e. can you run an external program and import the results later. I know some professional math programs, like sagemath, provide arbitrary precision real numbers. Yet it is hard to combine TeX and sagemath.

Comment: I can choose among several languages, export, then read+plot table in Latex.
But can I do all of this in Latex? I am writing a paper in Numerical Analysis, and the reviewers have suggested a free software. I think that pgf/tikz would be perfect.
\addplot coordinates {(0,1e-6000)} is allowed; this is high precision available.
Yesterday (April 29, 2020) was posted the Manual for ver 3.1.5b-34-gff02ccd1 [link](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf). 
In sect. 57.4.3, the fpu library allows \pgfmathfloattoextentedprecision{hxi} for extended precision. This is what I want :)

Comment: > all in LaTeX? Well if `fpu` allows extended/arbitrary precision then you are in good shape. My recommendation is to access `fpu` via `\pgfmathsetmacro` (the PGF interface, not the Ti*k*Z interface). Prepare your numbers outside the `tikzpicture` and store in an array or so. (`pgfkeys` serves as an array). The rest is just casual programming. You might need `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`, which does not introduce scope.

Comment: Thanks, @symbol 1. I have made the first steps, but I still need help. I have posted the new code. Somebody let me know how to perform the computations in `fpu`, how to keep the iterates in an array, and then how to plot them.

Answer (score 3):

The `xfp` package can be used here:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\printx#1{
  \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\x}
  \pgfmathfloattomacro{\pgfmathresult}{\F}{\M}{\E} 
  it: #1 Flags: \F; Mantissa \M; Exponent \E \par
}
\pgfmathfloatsetextprecision{3} %maximum precision
\begin{document}
\xdef\Nit{7}  % no of iterations
\def\x{0.5}  % x current, initialized, determining xnew
\printx{0}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\Nit} {
  \def\xn{\fpeval{\x -(\x + \x^2)/(1 + 2*\x)}}
  \xdef\x{\xn}  %update x
  \printx{\i}
}
\end{document}
```

## About Precision

The default math engine uses the TeX fixed numbers.

The fpu library uses floating numbers with variable precision (mantissa between around 5 and around 8 digits in base 10).

The xfp library uses float numbers with fixed precision (mantissa is around 16 digits in base 10).

For each library, the following document calculates `(10 ** i-1) - (10 ** i)` for increasing values of i until obtaining 0.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\begin{document}
\textbf{pfg default math engine (\TeX)}\par
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xdiff{(pow(10,\i)+1)-(pow(10,\i))}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\correct{(\xdiff!=0)?1:0}
  \i : $\num{\xdiff} = (10^{\i}+1)-(10^{\i})$ \par
  \ifnum 0 = \correct\relax
  \breakforeach
  \fi
}
5: \emph{dimension too large!}\par
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
\foreach \myprecision in {0,...,3}{
  \textbf{fpu with precision \myprecision}\par
  \pgfmathfloatsetextprecision{\myprecision}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,30}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xdiff{(pow(10,\i)+1)-(pow(10,\i))}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\correct{(\xdiff!=0)?1:0}
    \i : $\num{\xdiff} = (10^{\i}+1)-(10^{\i})$ \par
    \ifnum 0 = \correct\relax
    \breakforeach
    \fi
  }
}
\textbf{xfp}\par
\foreach \i in {1,...,30}{
  \edef\xdiff{\fpeval{(10**\i+1)-(10**\i)}}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\correct{(\xdiff!=0)?1:0}
  \i : $\num{\xdiff} = (10^{\i}+1)-(10^{\i})$ \par
  \ifnum 0 = \correct\relax
  \breakforeach
  \fi
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The following code shows the same result with `(2^\i)-(2^\i-1)`

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}


\begin{document}
\textbf{pfg default math engine (\TeX)}\par
\foreach \i in {10,...,13}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xdiff{(pow(2,\i)-(pow(2,\i)-1))}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\correct{(\xdiff!=0)?1:0}
  \i : $\num{\xdiff} = (2^{\i})-(2^{\i}-1)$ \par
  \ifnum 0 = \correct\relax
  \breakforeach
  \fi
}
14: \emph{! Dimension too large}\par
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
\foreach \myprecision in {0,...,3}{
  \textbf{fpu with precision \myprecision}\par
  \pgfmathfloatsetextprecision{\myprecision}
  \foreach \i in {12,...,30}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xdiff{(pow(2,\i))-(pow(2,\i)-1)}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\correct{(\xdiff!=0)?1:0}
    \i : $\num{\xdiff} = (2^{\i})-(2^{\i}-1)$ \par
    \ifnum 0 = \correct\relax
    \breakforeach
    \fi
  }
}
\textbf{xfp}\par
\foreach \i in {10,...,58}{
  \edef\xdiff{\fpeval{(2**\i)-(2**\i-1)}}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\correct{(\xdiff!=0)?1:0}
  \i : $\num{\xdiff} = (2^{\i})-(2^{\i}-1)$ \par
  \ifnum 0 = \correct\relax
  \breakforeach
  \fi
}
\end{document}
```

The result below shows that `xfp` uses a mantissa with 53 bits (+1 for the sign).

[image]

## Arbitrary Precision

For arbitrary precision, you can try the `xintexpr` package...

Comment: This version works only 7 steps, representing exponent till -31 (i.e., 10^-31). 
When representing the graph of 2^(-2^x), x=1,...,14 the exponents are allowed till -6500.

Comment: @bluesky It's a processor limit. Do you want to make a calculation with very high precision? What purpose ?

Comment: my aim is to promote `pgf/tikz` in a paper to be published in a math journal: numerical examples for Newton method solely by `Latex` (no other language).     
1e-31 we got it's not a processor limit: all processors obeying `IEEE-754` use double precision (the smallest number >0 is 2.2e-308).    
The plain `\plot` in `tikz` handles f(x)=2^(-2^x), x=1,...,14: f(14) =approx 1e-6500. This means much increased precision than double.

Comment: @bluesky The processor limit is about the mantissa. With `xfp`, it's about 16 digits. So, `1+2*\x` is `1` if `\x` is less than `1e-17`... And `\x +\x^2` is `\x`. And you got the exact solution: `0`!

Comment: and when computing/plotting f(x)=2^(-2^x), x=1...14 by `pgf/tikz` getting 1e-6500 the mantissa is still 16 digits? Hard to believe, as it hasn't much sense.     What if solving sin(x)=0 around pi, and we get it with just 5 digits??  In the last version of `pgf/tikz` documentation (3.1.5.b), section 57.4.3, `\pgfmathfloattoextentedprecision{hxi}` allows extended mantissa. But that's my problem, I don't know how to call/use.

Comment: @bluesky It seems to me that you are confusing the mantissa and the exponent. For the accuracy of the calculations, the mantissa is much more important than the exponent.

Comment: My confusion came from the terminology `extended precision` (in `fpu`).
Since the 80s, when the standards for real numbers were settled 
by hardware and software specialists, and IEEE-754 was adopted (see here
an interesting story
[link](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/754story.html), real numbers in single precision were represented
on 32 bits, double precision on 64 bits, and extended precision was
higher than double.

Extended means in `fpu` mantisa as for double, but with larger exponent...

Comment: @bluesky With `fpu`, `precision` (mantissa) and `range` (exponent) are _extended_  in comparison with the default math engine of `pgf`.

Comment: I think the above code should be replaced to the usual one to demonstrate the 
computation in each case of the [`machine epsilon`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).
Though defined as the smallest positive number greater than 1,
the [`machine epsilon`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) gives the relative error in performing the four math 
operations +,-,*,/. The algorithm is: 

    macheps = 1;
    
    while 1.0 + (macheps/2) > 1.0
         macheps = macheps / 2;
    end

Answer (score 0):

I hope this demonstrate my comment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{fpu}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

    \def\cs#1/{\texttt{\string#1}}

    Turn on fpu so \cs\pgfmathsetmacro/ and \cs\pgfmathparse/
    automatically convert the numbers to fpu notation.
    \tikzset{fpu=true}

    Maximum precision, three more decimal digits, or ten more binary digits.
    \pgfmathfloatsetextprecision{3}

    \xdef\Nit{9} Number of iterations = \Nit

    \def\x{0.5} Initial \cs\x/ = \x

    It is not necessary to turn \cs\x/ into fpu notation.
    But we can do it anyway.
    \pgfmathsetmacro\x{\x}
    New \cs\x/ = \x.

    Define a useful \cs\pgfkeys/ handler
    \def\pgfkeysgloballet#1#2{\global\expandafter\let\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname#2}
    \pgfkeys{/handlers/.let/.code=\pgfkeysgloballet{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{#1}}

\subsection{Iteration}

    Start the iteration

    \foreach \i in {1,...,\Nit} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xi{\x - (\x + \x^4)/(1 + 4*\x^3)}  % new x
        \pgfmathfloattomacro{\xi}{\F}{\M}{\E} 
        \i th iteration: Flags: \F; Mantissa \M; Exponent \E.
        \xdef\x{\xi} % update \xi
        Put \cs\x/ in array.
        \tikzset{/bluesky/Newton result/\i/.let=\xi}

    }

    PS. \cs\tikzset/ allows almost arbitrary string as path name.
    By using numbers in the path, you are creating an array.

\subsection{Using array}

    Now check the array
    \tikzset{/Newton result/3/.get=\thirdvalue}
    Third value is \thirdvalue.
    Good.

    Now try to recall the whole array

    \foreach \i in {1,...,\Nit} {
        \tikzset{/bluesky/Newton result/\i/.get=\xi}
        \i th iteration: \cs\xi/ = \xi.

    }


    Close the fpu engine because \texttt{tikzpicture} dislikes it.
    \tikzset{fpu=false}

    Now a tikz picture to illustrate how they cooperate.

    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.5]
        \draw[->](0,0)--(10,0);
        \draw[->](0,0)--(0,10);
        \foreach\i in{1,...,\Nit}{
            % we want to extract the number
            \tikzset{/bluesky/Newton result/\i/.get=\xi}
            \draw(\i,\i)node{\xi};
            % \xi is an fpu number, take log
            \draw(\i,10-\i-.5)node{\pgfmathfloatlogten{\xi}\pgfmathresult};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}

    Now the real picture

    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.5]
        \draw[->](0,0)--(10,0);
        \draw[->](0,0)--(0,10);
        \foreach\i in{1,...,\Nit}{
            % we want to extract the number
            \tikzset{/bluesky/Newton result/\i/.get=\xi}
            \pgfmathfloatlogten{\xi}
            \let\logtenxi=\pgfmathresult
            \pgfmathfloattofixed{\logtenxi}
            \let\logtenxi=\pgfmathresult
            % check if nan
            \def\textnan{nan}
            \ifx\logtenxi\textnan
                % wow, nan, cannot plot
                \draw(\i,3)node{failed};
            \else
                \draw(\i,-\logtenxi)node{good};
            \fi
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}

    See the documentation of \cs\pgfmathfloatifflags/
    to know how to test nan properly.

\subsection{Alternative}

    You can also turn on and off fpu before \texttt{tikzpicture}
    so that you can do log of floating number with \cs\pgfmathparse/.

    The following is the equivalent of python's map

    \tikzset{fpu=true}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\Nit} {
        \tikzset{/bluesky/Newton result/\i/.get=\xi}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\mlogxi{-log10(\xi)}
        \tikzset{/bluesky/Newton result/logged/\i/.let=\mlogxi}
    }
    \tikzset{fpu=false}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.5]
        \draw[->](0,0)--(10,0);
        \draw[->](0,0)--(0,10);
        \draw(0,0)node(prev point){};
        \foreach\i in{1,...,\Nit}{
            % extract the number
            \tikzset{/bluesky/Newton result/logged/\i/.get=\mlogxi}
            \pgfmathfloatifflags\mlogxi{+}{
                % is positive
                \def\GorB{good}
                \pgfmathfloattofixed{\mlogxi}
                \let\yvalue=\pgfmathresult
            }{
                % is probably nan
                \def\GorB{bad}
                \def\yvalue{4}
            }
            \draw(\i,\yvalue)node(this point){\GorB};
            \draw[>->](prev point)--(this point);
            \pgfnodealias{prev point}{this point}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for showing to me precisely what I need.
As I have commented above, when reading in the `pgf/tikz ver. 3.1.5.b-...`
doc. that `fpu` can handle `extended precision`, I thought this means, as usually,
"more precise than double", but actually only the exponent is
represented on more bits (the mantissa is represented as for `double precision`).
As for quadruple order for Newton method (e.g., f(x)=x+x^4,
xn = x - (x+x^4)/(1+4*x^3), x0=0.5) we obtain only two nonzero iterates,
I need numbers with much extended mantissa. I am modifying the above example you provided, if ok.

Comment: I was confused too. So pgf wasn't perfect in terms of the precision. But I believe other packages can help.